# How to create new AutoML DataSet for simple classification (C#)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-automl

As part of ML automation process I want to dynamically create new AutoML model. I'm using C# (.net framework) and [Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/2.0.0/index.html).

After trying to run `CreateDataSet` code:

```
var autoMlClient = AutoMlClient.Create();
var parent = LocationName.FromProjectLocation(_projectId, _locationId);

var dataset = new Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1.Dataset();
dataset.DisplayName = "NewDataSet";    
var response = autoMlClient.CreateDataset(parent, dataset);
```

I get the following error:

> Field: dataset.dataset_metadata; Message: Required field not set

According to this [user manual](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.datasets) I should set `Dataset Metadata Type`, but the list contains only specific types of classifications (Translation/ImageClassifications etc.), I can't find a simple classification type.
How do I create a simple classification data set with the API ? in the AutoML UI its just with a simple button click ("NEW DATASET") - and have to provide only name & region - no classification type.

I also tried to set:

```
dataset.TextClassificationDatasetMetadata = 
     new TextClassificationDatasetMetadata() { ClassificationType = ClassificationType.Multiclass };
```

But I was unable to import data to it (got too many errors of invalid inputs from the input CSV file), I guess its related to the reason that the input format is not suitable for Text Classification.

UPDATE

I've just notice that the Nuget works with [AutoML v1](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.datasets) but [v1 beta](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.datasets) does contains `TablesDatasetMetadata` Dataset Metadata Type for normal classifications. I'm speechless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @RajithaWarusavitarana comment, and my last question update , below is the code that did the trick. The token is being generated by `GoogleClientAPI` nuget and AutoML is handled by REST.

```
string GcpGlobalEndPointUrl = "https://automl.googleapis.com";
string GcpGlobalLocation = "us-central1";   // api "parent" parameter

public string GetToken(string jsonFilePath)
{
    var serviceAccountCredentialFileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);

    var credentialParameters = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<JsonCredentialParameters>(serviceAccountCredentialFileContents);
    var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(credentialParameters.ClientEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new List<string> { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" }
    };
    var cred = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer.FromPrivateKey(credentialParameters.PrivateKey));

    string accessToken = cred.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token").Result;
    return accessToken;
}

public void GetDataSetList(string projectId, string token)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient(GcpGlobalEndPointUrl);

    var createDataSetReqUrl = $"v1beta1/projects/{projectId}/locations/{GcpGlobalLocation}/datasets";
    var createDataSetReq = new RestRequest(createDataSetReqUrl, Method.GET);
    createDataSetReq.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

    var createDatasetResponse = restClient.Execute(createDataSetReq);
    createDatasetResponse.Dump();
}
```

I took the token generation code from [google-api-dotnet-client Test File](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/731fe5efc19e82c3632f2a55b6b646dca978759d/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.Tests/OAuth2/ServiceAccountCredentialTests.cs)

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this scenario today while creating a dataset using the NodeJS client. Since the Google AutoML table service is in the beta level you need to use the beta version of the AutoML client. In the  [Google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/import)  they have used the beta client to create a dataset.

In NodeJS importing the beta version `require('@google-cloud/automl').v1beta1.AutoMlClient` instead of importing the normal version (v1) `require('@google-cloud/automl').v1` worked for me to successfully execute the create dataset functionality.

In C# you can achieve the same through a [POST request](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/import#automl-tables-example-drest). Hope this helps :)

Comment: you right! unfortunatly C# do not has the beta library.